# Where do I get started with rendering curved space?

Tags: geometry, programming, noneuclidean-geometry

I want to program interactive renderings of spaces of arbitrary curvature (such as spherical or hyperbolic), though I have no idea how to begin. For instance, I have no idea whether I should use rasterization or ray tracing. I also have very few sources that cover what I'm trying to accomplish. I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction, share some relevant math, or tell me a bit about curved space.

Specific Questions:

- Should I use ray tracing or rasterization?
- What are some helpful sources I could use to work on this project?
- Are there any particular formulas I should know for this project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.geometrygames.org/CurvedSpaces/index.html.en

This may be useful, as the source code is available.

Comment: I'm sure [Zeno Rogue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265219/zeno-rogue) could answer your questions.